# javascript function with json values

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am trying to compute the average in a function and fetching values from a json obj. Can anyone please tell where am I wrong here. I am sure there is something wrong with the average function. 
http://jsfiddle.net/NLaSJ/

```
var json = '[{  "firstName"  : "Stone", "lastName" : "Carpentar", "Salary1" : "600", "Salary2" :  "200" "}, {"firstName":"Samson", "lastName":  "Sears", "Salary1" :  "200", "Salary2":"500"}]';

var emp = JSON.parse(json);
for (var i = 0; i < emp.length; i++) {
    var msg = emp[i];
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = msg.firstName + '&nbsp' + msg.lastName + '&nbsp' + msg.Age + '&nbsp' + 'AverageSalary' + computeAverage(msg.salary1, msg.salary2);

    document.body.appendChild(div);

}


function computeAverage(msg.salary1, msg.salary2) {
    return (msg.salary1 + msg.salary2) / 2;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: it should be function computeAverage(salary1, salary2)

Comment: not sure how to access the json data in the function

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome debugger to find errors. Localize errors by putting in debug statements or commenting out lines. You have an extra quote in the json: "Salary2" :  "200" " < - here.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON uses "Salary1" and "Salary2", but your code is all lower-case. JavaScript (and JSON) are case-sensitive.

Also, your "computeAverage()" function declaration is syntactically wrong.

Also, your JSON string has a stray double-quote character in it.

Also, in your JSON the numeric values are quoted like strings, and they should not be.

Comment: Thanks Pointy. I fixed those issue but still I am not getting the expected result. I guess the computeAverage is not executed as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/NLaSJ/17/

Comment: thanks I guess that was the issue. I just started learning JSON and the first place I went was w3schools and they were including the values like strings. but anyways thanks a ton

Comment: It's a good idea to [avoid w3schools](http://w3fools.com) :-)  StackOverflow is a great resource too of course.